# Remove div on the click of a link that was created dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code, when a checkbox is clicked it creates a div with some info.  However in that div I added an anchor tag to remove the div itself.

However, I am not sure how to remove the div on the link click because the div is dynamically generated.

```
//Add selected job in the results div
function AddSelectedJob(id, display) {
    //create a div for every selected job
    $("[id$=ResultsDiv]").append('<div class="selectedjobs" id=' + id + '>' + display + '<a href="#">Remove selected job</a></div>');
}
```

Comment: Try remove this.parent() jquery code

Comment: Off topic but interesting read concerning href=#. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134845/href-attribute-for-javascript-links-or-javascriptvoid0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**USE THIS CODE :-**

//Add selected job in the results div

```
function AddSelectedJob(id, display) {
    //create a div for every selected job
    $("[id$=ResultsDiv]").append('<div class="selectedjobs" id=' + id + '>' + display + '<a href="javascript:;" onclick="removeSelectedJob(this)">Remove selected job</a></div>');
}

function removeSelectedJob(el){
    $(el).parent().remove();
}
```

Comment: I understand you're tempted to use this quick fix, using the onclick attribute is inflexible and imo unwanted because I would like my JS seperate from my HTML. And using this you can only add 1 event handler. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget.addEventListener#Why_use_addEventListener.3F

Answer (score 4):

```
$(document).on('click','.selectedjobs a',function(){
       $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: delgating it to the closest static parent is better  `[id$=ResultsDiv]`  in this case

Answer (score 4):

give your `div` a class and use `on` delegate event

try this

```
$("[id$=ResultsDiv]").append('<div class="selectedjobs" id=' + id + '>' + display + '<a href="#" class="removeJob">Remove selected job</a></div>');

$('[id$=ResultsDiv]').on('click','.removeJob',function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
})
```

OR

without using class

```
$('[id$=ResultsDiv]').on('click','.selectedjobs a',function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
})
```

**note: delgating it to the closest static parent container is better than the `document` itself**

[link](http://jq4you.blogspot.com/2013/02/jquery-direct-and-delegate-on-event.html) to read more about `on` events

Answer (score 0):

something like:

```
$("#ResultsDiv>div.selectedjobs a").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Comment: Good point! well I will let this answer here to point out that you should not use my answer ;) Thanks Johan!

Answer (score 0):

Try live click...

```
$(".selectedjobs a").live("click", function(){
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case divs are not usually created but are rather hidden instead by which you would a lot of hassle. You can create a div that has "display:none;" in CSS and then when the tickbox is checked you can use

```
$("[id$=ResultsDiv]").show();
```

and when it is unchecked,

```
$("[id$=ResultsDiv]").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using .parents() in this case.

And if possible, add a class to your anchor, then return false or use .preventDefault() to prevent anchor's default action.

```
//Add selected job in the results div
function AddSelectedJob(id, display) {
    //create a div for every selected job
    $("[id$=ResultsDiv]").append('<div class="selectedjobs" id=' + id + '>' + display + '<a class="removeSelectedJobs" href="#">Remove selected job</a></div>');
}

$('.selectedjobs .removeSelectedJobs').live('click', function() {
    $(this).parents('.selectedjobs').remove();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: live() was removed from jQuery few versions ago. Instead of use on(), also works like .live() :)