# Add and remove checkbox events dynamically depending on some business logic?

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Scenario:**

I have a results table with a checkbox, when the checkbox is checked, the content of the row(actually 2 columns concateneted only, are copied to a new div, with the job code and job name).  This works pretty well, and I am avoiding duplicated already.
However, in the new results div, I am creating an anchor tag to remove the div itself.
After the div has been removed, I should be able to add the selected job again with the checkbox.
Please note that there are many jobs in the results table, so putting the flag to false again will not work.

***Also if you find a better title for this question, please let me know***

```
    //On every checkbow that is clicked
    var flag = false;
    $("#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_myGrid input").change(function () {
        if (this.checked && flag === false) {
            flag = true;
            var jobCode = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find("td:eq(2)").text()
            var jobName = $(this).parent().parent().parent().find("td:eq(1)").text()
            var displayvalue = jobCode.toUpperCase() + " - " + jobName.toUpperCase();                      
            AddSelectedJob(jobCode, displayvalue);
            //$(this).unbind('change'); //Unbind the change event so that it doesnt fire again
            FillSelectedJobs();            
        }
    });



//Add selected job in the results div
function AddSelectedJob(id, display) {
    //create a div for every selected job
    $("[id$=ResultsDiv]").append('<div class="selectedjobs" id=' + id + '>' + display + '<a href="javascript:;" onclick="removeSelectedJob(this)">Remove selected job</a></div>');
}

//Removes the selected job from the resutls div
function removeSelectedJob(el) {
    $(el).parent().remove();
}
```

The generated html is like this:

```
<div>
            <div style="height: 300px; overflow: auto; float: left">
                <div>
        <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_myGrid" style="color:#333333;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;">
            <tr style="color:White;background-color:#5D7B9D;font-weight:bold;">
                <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th><th scope="col">JobCode</th><th scope="col">JobName</th><th scope="col">JobPartner</th><th scope="col">JobManager</th><th scope="col">ClientName</th>
            </tr><tr style="color:#333333;background-color:#F7F6F3;">
                <td>
                                <input id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_myGrid_ctl02_CheckBox1" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$myGrid$ctl02$CheckBox1" />
                            </td><td>jobcode01</td><td>jobname</td><td>xx</td><td>xx</td><td>xx</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
            </div>
            <div style="margin-top: 0px; margin-left: 10px; float: left">
                <span>Selected :</span>
                <div id="ResultsDiv" style="margin-top: 0px">
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Avoid this `.parent().parent().parent()`. Check http://api.jquery.com/parents/ and http://api.jquery.com/closest/

Comment: just maintaining someone else's code, I agree that code looks ugly, how can I fix that?

Comment: and you need to learn how to format the question too.. :)

Comment: @Luis, see [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) @elclanrs linked to. Here it would be something like `.closest("table")`

Comment: @bipen the question is already formatted, the code is formatted what else you want?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly I suggest some changes to your HTML. Separate out the styles from your DOM and place them in classes.

This makes sure there is separation of concerns

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <div class="divMain">
        <div>
            <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" 
                     id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_myGrid" class="table">
                <tr class="rowHead">
                    <th scope="col">&nbsp;</th>
                    <th scope="col">JobCode</th>
                    <th scope="col">JobName</th>
                    <th scope="col">JobPartner</th>
                    <th scope="col">JobManager</th>
                    <th scope="col">ClientName</th>
                </tr>
                <tr class="row">
                    <td>
                        <input id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_myGrid_ctl02_CheckBox1" 
                           type="checkbox" 
                          name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$myGrid$ctl02$CheckBox1"
                          data-flag="false" />
                    </td>
                    <td>column1</td>
                    <td>column2</td>
                    <td>column3</td>
                    <td>column4</td>
                    <td>column5</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="m0 selected"> 
        <span>Selected :</span>
        <div id="ResultsDiv" class="m0"></div>
    </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.divMain{
    height: 300px;
    overflow: auto;
    float: left
}

.table{
    color:#333333;
    width:100%;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}

.rowHead{    
    color:White;
    background-color:#5D7B9D;
    font-weight:bold;
}

.row{
 color:#333333;
 background-color:#F7F6F3;   
}

.m0{
     margin-top: 0px;   
}

.selected{
    margin-left: 10px;
    float: left
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$("#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_myGrid input").change(function () {
    // Next cache your selector
    // so that you need not crawl the DOM multiple times
    var $this = $(this),
        $row = $this.closest('.row'),
        currFlag = Boolean($this.data('flag'));

    // As there might be multiple jobs , a single flag variable  
    // will not work. So you can set a data-flag attribute on the 
    // input that stores the current value
    if (currFlag === false && this.checked) {
        // Set the corresponding flag to true
        $this.data('flag', true);
        var jobCode = $row.find("td:eq(2)").text(),
            jobName = $row.find("td:eq(1)").text(),
            displayvalue = jobCode.toUpperCase() + " - " 
                         + jobName.toUpperCase(),
            inputId =  $this.attr('id')
        // Pass the input name too as you need to set the value of
        // the corresponding flag value again as you can add it multiple times         
        AddSelectedJob(jobCode, displayvalue, inputId);
        FillSelectedJobs();
    }
});

//Add selected job in the results div
function AddSelectedJob(id, display, inputId) {
    //create a div for every selected job
    // Use the inputId to save it as a data-id attribute  
    // on anchor so that you can set the value of the flag after 
    // removing it
    var html = '<div class="selectedjobs" id=' + id + '>' + display ;
    html += '<a href="javascript" data-id="'+ inputId 
                                 +'">Remove selected job</a></div>';                   
    $('[id$=ResultsDiv]').append(html);
}

// Remove the inline click event for the anchor and delgate it to the 
// static parent container
$('[id$=ResultsDiv]').on('click', 'a', function(e) {
    var $this = $(this),
        $currentCheckbox = $this.data('id');
    // Set the flag value of the input back to false

    $('#'+ $currentCheckbox).data('flag', false);
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the default action of the anchor
    $this.closest('.selectedjobs').remove();
});


function FillSelectedJobs() {
    //save values into the hidden field
    var selectedJobs = $("[id$=ResultsDiv]").find("[class$='selectedjobs']");
    var returnvalue = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < selectedJobs.length; i++)
        returnvalue += selectedJobs[i].id + ";";
    $("[id$=HiddenClientCode]").val(returnvalue);
}
```

**[Check Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/b67KA/)**

Comment: Each input will have a extra attribute called `data-flag="false"`

Comment: @LuisValencia.. Check updated code.. Now should be working for multiple rows tooo :)

Comment: when I added the dataflag on the gridview. like this: <Columns>
                        <asp:TemplateField>
                            <ItemTemplate>
                                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" data-flag="false" />
                            </ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:TemplateField>
                    </Columns>, its generated in span outside the checkbox    <span data-flag="false"><input id="ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_myGrid_ctl02_CheckBox1" type="checkbox" name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$myGrid$ctl02$CheckBox1" /></span>

Comment: If that is the case try replacing `data-flag=false` with `flag= true` . And in jQuery `.data` has to be replaced with `.attr`

Comment: Otherwise you could do one more hing, just remove the `data-flag=false` attribute completely and write this up before change event `$("#ctl00_PlaceHolderMain_myGrid input").each(function() { $(this).data('flag', false); });`

Comment: @LuisValencia.. Glad to have helped :)